# How to convert existing ubuntu installation into iso [ GUI ]

Tags: software-installation, live-usb, backup, live-cd, ubuntu-minimal

> I reed this [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)
>
> but it's so hard to go throw all these steps & I'm asking for GUI

---

I have an installation of Ubuntu with a system size over `21 GB`

I need to transfer my system to another hard disk but not my user data..

it will be useful if there is a tool to help creating live CD [ either full or minimal ]

---

> I tried those
>
> - **pinguybuilder** [pinguybuilder-menu-based_5.2-1_all](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/)
>
>   didn't create the iso due ro large size also so slow
> - **relinux** [relinux_0.4a1-5_amd64](https://launchpad.net/relinux)
>
>   Did't know how to use it
> - **linux-live** [site](https://www.linux-live.org/) | [Github](https://github.com/Tomas-M/linux-live)
>
>   created iso but it has strange structure and not bootable
> - **customizer** [Github](https://github.com/kamilion/customizer)
>
>   iso cant be created due to large size

Comment: Why not just reinstall Ubuntu? And restore from your normal backup which you should have anyway for when hard drive breaks and you have to do it that way. If you do not want your data, you need the mostly hidden configuration files in /home. If you changed any system setting those would be in /etc/ If server apps, you also need those. And export list of installs apps to make it easy to reinstall. Is your data in separate /home or data partition(s)?

Comment: As I need to change the hard drive I'm working with from time to time.. it would help if having live iso to work on or reinstall.. I'm not working with one hard drive but I always have a usb

Comment: I have a full install in most of my larger flash drives 16GB or more. And then add ISO for grub to loopmount boot of Ubuntu, gparted & others for emergency repair. I do not use flash drive for regular use as they have a more limited life. I just saw a user to put a NVMe SSD into a USB case and used that for booting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot convert an installed system into an iso file in an easy way. The tools that you link to have been used and can be used, but they are not easy to to use.

That said, I can describe a method that is much easier:

### Ubuntu OEM install

- Create the system that you want to distribute by installing a fresh system.
- Treat the installed system (that you want to distribute) by installing program packages, tweaking the system language and other settings and maybe adding desktop files and other common user files according to the following link,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview)

  into an OEM install system.
- Distribute [compressed] cloned images (img files) to the end users. (This is how systems for Raspberry Pi are distributed.)
- When an end user installs the system, the user ID, password and computer's network ID will be created so that they will be unique.

An Ubuntu OEM system is an *installed* system, which is portable between computers, much more so than Windows, but not as portable as a live Ubuntu system made from an iso file.

This will work, if the computers are fairly similar, and particularly if no proprietary drivers are necessary. So if your computer works best with some proprietary driver, typically for graphics or wifi, you had better not install it and rely on the built-in linux drivers. The end user can install a proprietary driver if necessary and maybe some boot option if needed for some hardware, for example `nomodeset` for newer and more powerful nvidia graphics.

Comment: That's good.. but I still can't test it unless I format my system.. also I need to do that with my existing system and keep it ready when ever I need to install it not with a fresh installation

Comment: It is a good idea to use another computer for testing. At the very least you should have some extra drives (HDD or SSD) for testing. Maybe you can borrow a computer for testing or ask a friend, colleague or customer to help testing your systems.

Comment: Aren't there any other way to obtain a live version of my system.. or does that proccess could be made with virtualbox or any thing that doesn't allow me to format tell the end

Comment: If you have a fast USB 3 pendrive that is big enough for the image, you can use that for testing, (or better with an SSD in an external box). Install Ubuntu into your external drive according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312). An installed system in a USB drive works 'sort of' like a live system.

Comment: You can make a system for VirtualBox, but then I am afraid that the end users must also use it in VirtualBox. That may or may not be OK.